# application testing with PHPSpec and PHPUnit

Tags: php, testing, laravel, phpunit, phpspec

Is it possible to with two different testing methodologies? For example PHPUnit and PHPSpec in the one applicationor package?

Does anyone have any guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use PHPSpec and PHPUnit in the same application. Or you could use something like Codeception (http://codeception.com/) which does Unit Testing, Functional Testing and Acceptance Testing all in one package.